# Filter Linq with Guid Stored in Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, guid

I am using this code to filter Linq data and it keeps crashing.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    var model = db.Tickets
            .Include(t => t.TicketNotes)
            .Where(t => t.OpenUserId == Guid.Parse(Session["LogedUserID"] as string))
            .OrderBy(t => t.OpenDate)
            .ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

The error I get is:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

The error I know is on this line:

```
.Where(t => t.OpenUserId == Guid.Parse(Session["LogedUserID"] as string))
```

because it was working when the Guid was hardcoded as in this case:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    var model = db.Tickets
                  .Include(t=>t.TicketNotes)
                  .Where(t.OpenUserId == new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"))
                  .OrderBy(t=>t.OpenDate);

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this error because the Linq code is transformed in SQL. In SQL the method `Guid.Parse` don't exists.

In your example with `Where(t.OpenUserId == new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"))` **you are not parsing anything** (calling any method), you are just create a new `Guid` which is supported.

A way will be to `Parse` the `Guid` outside `Where`.

```
var userId = Guid.Parse(Session["LogedUserID"] as string); // conversion is done outside Where
var model = db.Tickets
        .Include(t => t.TicketNotes)
        .Where(t => t.OpenUserId == userId)
        .OrderBy(t => t.OpenDate)
        .ToList();
```

Another easy way to fix this is by adding `ToList()`. As @entropic mentioned this will enumerate through entire table and is not recommended for large tables.

```
var model = db.Tickets
        .Include(t => t.TicketNotes)
        .ToList() // < added here
        .Where(t => t.OpenUserId == Guid.Parse(Session["LogedUserID"] as string))
        .OrderBy(t => t.OpenDate)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Absolutely, that's why conversion needs to be done before Linq expression.

Comment: Adding `.ToList()` will enumerate the entire table... which is probably the worst thing to do if it would grow to be large.  Your second example is better... but it still calls `.ToList()` on the entire table....

Comment: @entropic Thank you for highlighting this, I added on my answer. In the second example is a copy paste mistake (It shouldn't call `.ToList()`) Thank you so much for spotting this.

Answer (score 4):

Please try this, should work

```
Guid g = Guid.Parse(Session["LogedUserID"] as string);

var model = db.Tickets
                .Include(t => t.TicketNotes)
                .Where(t => t.OpenUserId == g)
                .OrderBy(t => t.OpenDate)
                .ToList();
```